# filter li elements by current browser url

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

im currently trying to put active class to the navigation by trying to detect the browser url... my code looks like

```
    $('[ui-nav] a, [data-ui-nav] a').filter( function() {
        console.log(location.href)
        console.log($(this).attr('href'))
        return location.href.indexOf( $(this).attr('href') ) != -1;
    }).parent().addClass( 'active' );
```

the output:

```
app.js:12758 http://localhost:8000/blog/welcome-to-my-blog
app.js:12759 /
app.js:12758 http://localhost:8000/blog/welcome-to-my-blog
app.js:12759 /blog
app.js:12758 http://localhost:8000/blog/welcome-to-my-blog
app.js:12759 /profile
app.js:12758 http://localhost:8000/blog/welcome-to-my-blog
app.js:12759 /test
```

my navigation:

```
Home -> /
Blog -> /blog
Profile -> /profile
Testing -> /test



<ul class="nav" data-ui-nav>
    <li class="nav-header hidden-folded">
        <span class="text-xs text-muted">Main</span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="/">
            <span class="nav-icon">
                <i class="material-icons">
                    play_circle_outline
                </i>
            </span>
            <span class="nav-text">Home</span>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="/blog">
            <span class="nav-icon">
                <i class="material-icons">
                    play_circle_outline
                </i>
            </span>
            <span class="nav-text">Blog</span>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="/profile">
            <span class="nav-icon">
                <i class="material-icons">
                    play_circle_outline
                </i>
            </span>
            <span class="nav-text">Profile</span>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="/test">
            <span class="nav-icon">
                <i class="material-icons">
                    play_circle_outline
                </i>
            </span>
            <span class="nav-text">Testing</span>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

by this example the Home and Blog li get an active class.. if anybody could give me a hint how to correct this short code i would be happy :)

best regards

Comment: Can you give us the html code that you want to match against? (A working example in the stackoverflow code editor would be best)

Answer (score 1):

try comparing the `pathname` properties instead

```
return location.pathname === this.pathname;
```

Examples of  link pathnames:

```js
$('a').each(function(){
   console.log('Link pathname: ', this.pathname);
});
```

```css
a{display:inline-block; padding:5px 10px; background:yellow}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="https://stackoverflow.com/test">https://stackoverflow.com/test</a>
<a href="/profile">/profile</a>
<a href="/">/</a>
```

Comment: thanks charlietfl for this solution, with this i get the right matches... but it fail on /blog/welcome-to-my-blog it shows nothing

Comment: Log both values to console to manually compare so can figure out what causes it not to match

Answer (score 0):

ive founded a solution that work.. okay its not the best, but im a newbie ;)

```
    $('[ui-nav] a, [data-ui-nav] a').filter( function() {
        if ($(this).attr('href') === '/') {
            if (location.pathname === $(this).attr('href')) {
                return true
            } else { return false }
        } else {
            return location.href.indexOf( $(this).attr('href') ) != -1;
        }
    }).parent().addClass( 'active' );
```